# Git stash apply leaves extra string in files

Tags: android, git, android-studio, git-stash

I have an Android Sstudio project that has `git` enabled.
git works fine but it does something wrong in `git stash apply`.
That adds these lines in modified files:
`=======`, `>>>>>>> Stashed changes`, `<<<<<<< Updated upstream`
and corrupts the project.
Don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Use git status to show your stash state.

Comment: As Larry Schiefer answered, you have a merge conflict. I would add here that this happens *because* `git stash save` just makes commits (that are on no branch), and `git stash apply` performs a merge (the verb form of merge), so that you get all the fun of dealing with Git merges, with none of the benefit of making your own commits. For these reasons I am always hesitant to suggest `git stash` to new Git users: it's great when it works, but when it goes wrong, you *need* to know a lot about Git!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have a conflict in your stashed changes vs. the latest upstream.  When you applied the stash you should have seen an error about a merge conflict.  You'll have to manually edit the file(s) to resolve the conflict, then you should be able to build.

Comment: that lines indicates those files has conflict?

Comment: After resolving conflicts don't forget to `git add` and `git commit`. Also look at `git stash list` and decide what to drop using `git stash drop`.

Comment: A word of warning on that: if all you wish to do is *apply* the stash and not commit it, then after resolving the conflict just run `git reset` to reset the index but leave the files in their modified state.